# C# byte array length inferior to python

Tags: c#, python, byte

I'm trying to port some Python code to C# and in the code there is a part where it encrypts a string with AES with the following key:

> '\xd7\xdf\xca2\xd0Vhu\xeb\x06\xa0\xba\n\xa2\x07O\xc1\x8b\xcf\x8f2&t\xc0\x92\xc4\xa5\x0b>\xb4\xe7\xbc'

This key is 32 bytes in Python, but the problem is that in C# it is 30 bytes when I convert that string (`Encoding.Default.GetBytes`), so I can't generate the AES key.

**Why is the length of the key 32 in Python and the byte array length is 30 in C#?**

Converting the key to bytes array:

```
byte[] key = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("\xd7\xdf\xca2\xd0Vhu\xeb\x06\xa0\xba\n\xa2\x07O\xc1\x8b\xcf\x8f2&t\xc0\x92\xc4\xa5\x0b>\xb4\xe7\xbc");
```

Getting invalid key size for algorithm exception (because it's 30 bytes and not 32):

```
byte[] encrypted;
byte[] iv;
using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
{
    aesAlg.Key = key;
    aesAlg.GenerateIV();
    iv = aesAlg.IV;
    aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

    var encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, iv);

    using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
            {
                swEncrypt.Write("test");
            }
            encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your example.  Also:  http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ and http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Comment: Sorry I am new to this, edited with more infos

Comment: Your example code does not even compile....

Comment: i was missing the vector bytes array it should be ok now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The byte string you have is in a sort of mixed encoding, with unicode code-points and ASCII representations of characters alongside each-other. You can see this in a few places,

> '\xd7\xdf\xca**2**\xd0**Vhu**\xeb\x06\xa0\xba **\n**\xa2\x07**O**\xc1\x8b\xcf\x8f**2&t**\xc0\x92\xc4\xa5\x0b **>**\xb4\xe7\xbc'

If you convert those over to codepoints, you end up with `"\xd7\xdf\xca\x32\xd0\x56\x68\x75\xeb\x06\xa0\xba\x0a\xa2\x07\x4f\xc1\x8b\xcf\x8f\x32\x26\x74\xc0\x92\xc4\xa5\x0b\x3e\xb4\xe7\xbc"`, and should have the correct bytes for your key.

```
var val = "\xd7\xdf\xca\x32\xd0\x56\x68\x75\xeb\x06\xa0\xba\x0a\xa2\x07\x4f\xc1\x8b\xcf\x8f\x32\x26\x74\xc0\x92\xc4\xa5\x0b\x3e\xb4\xe7\xbc";
var count = Encoding.Default.GetByteCount(val);
Console.WriteLine(count); // 32
```

Comment: Thank you a lot it works, didn't know c# doesn't support this ! Have a nice day:)

Comment: It is a sequence of binary bytes expressed as an ASCII character when possible and as a hex escaped value otherwise as shown in the last line of the answer.